# MPLAB X doesn't try to connect

Tags: programmer, mplabx

I'm new to MPLAB X and I run into trouble right away.

I want to read/write the program memory and EEPROM of a chip because I have a corrupted chip and a correct HEX file.

I created a project, entered the PIC p/n and selected PICKit3. In the projrct properties I enabled target power. Then I went to read the flash of the chip using the toolbar button. It does nothing. In the Program Memory window I don't see any code. In the output I just see:

```
Connecting to programmer...
```

Interestingly, when I disconnect the programmer, it does the same. When I select the wrong programmer in the project properties (e.g. ICD2), it still does the same. In the output window the messages of `Connecting to programmer...` keep accumulating without ever saying anything else. In the IDE log, nothing appears either.

I checked if the programmer is installed in Device Manager. When I connect it, a HID Input Device appears.

Edit: I downloaded MPLAB 8.92 and it works instantly without any trouble.

Comment: Try to use MPLAB IPE instead, I find that it gives far less trouble then MPLAB X when it comes to connecting the programmer.

Comment: Make sure that the device is "fully" recognized by Windows (i.e. make sure the hardware detection thingy in the taskbar isn't spinning). You will see both a "HID-compliant device" and "USB Input Device" under Human Interface Devices in Device Manager.  Once it is recognized, you may need to wait for MPLAB X to upgrade the firmware and bootloader of the PICkit3, but you will see this on-screen at least.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that you have the wrong drivers for the PICKIT, I would not expect it to enumerate as a HID device. My ICD3 enumerates as a Microchip custom USB Device. Use Device Manager to uninstall the PICKIT, then disconnect it, wait 20s (Windows seems to take 10 to 20s to recognize that I have disconnected the ICD3), then plug it in again. Windows should install the device again, but hopefully with the correct drivers. Pay attention to the messages Windows gives you in case it cannot find the correct drivers, this may have happened last time.

Comment: PICkit3 *is* purely HID - there are no drivers whatsoever for it. This is why you don't need to use the driver switcher with it. You can see it for yourself when it's plugged in: HID \ VID 04D8 \ PID 900A. ICD3 and REAL ICE use WinUSB drivers for much improved debug capability and throughput.

Comment: Page 18 of the PICkit3 user's guide (DS52116A) confirms HID.

Comment: PICKit3 works in MPLAB 8.92